# shell: how to read a certain column in a certain line into a variable

Tags: shell

I want to extract the first column of the last line of a text file. Instead of output the content of interest in another file and read it in again, can I just use some command to read it into a variable directly?
For exampole, if my file is like this:

```
...  
123 456 789(this is the last line)
```

What I want is to read 123 into a variable in my shell script. How can I do that?

Comment: The *last* line, as opposed to a numbered line? That's a whole different thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, the last line. I'm not sure about the number of the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to extract the line you want, read its columns into an array, and emit the array element you want.

For the last line:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- not /bin/sh, to enable arrays and process substitution

read -r -a columns < <(tail -n 1 "$filename") # put last line's columns into an array
echo "${columns[0]}"                          # emit the first column
```

---

Alternately, `awk` is an appropriate tool for the job:

```
line=2
column=1
var=$(awk -v line="$line" -v col="$column" 'NR == line { print $col }' <"$filename")
echo "Extracted the value: $var"
```

---

That said, if you're looking for a line close to the start of a file, it's often faster (in a runtime-performance sense) and easier to stick to shell builtins. For instance, to take the third column of the second line of a file:

```
{
  read -r _           # throw away first line
  read -r _ _ value _ # extract third value of second line
} <"$filename"
```

This works by using `_`s as placeholders for values you don't want to read.

Comment: With `awk`, why not `var=$(awk -v line="$line" 'NR == line { print $1 }')` for the first column of the line number in `$line`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, because I didn't want to hardcode `$1`. The question is asking for a general solution, after all. I'm sure there's a way to index into the columns for a variable-based position, but my awk-fu isn't as strong as my shell-fu.

Comment: OK: so `var=$(awk -v line="$line" -v col="$col" 'NR == line { print $col }')`?  Or even: `var=$(awk -v line="$line" -v col="${col:-1}" 'NR == line { print $col }')`.  Awk makes it trickier to deal with 'last line'. I'll need to think about that.  I also seem to have lost the data source.

Answer (score 0):

I guess with "first column", you mean "first word", do you?

If it is guaranteed, that the last line doesn't start with a space, you can do

```
tail -n 1 YOUR_FILE | cut -d ' ' -f 1
```

Comment: Yes, I do mean the first word, which is not a space, but a real number I want to use in later commands. Can you be more specific? I mean how to assign the content to a variable. Because this is also the part that puzzles me. I use `a=$(tail -n 1 myfile | cut -d ' ' -f 1)`, but `echo "a=${a}"` shows "a=". But the first word of my line is not a space.

Comment: It works for me. What does `echo "/$(tail -n 1 myfile)/"`  and `tail -n 1 myfile | od -cx` print?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use sed: 
`$> var=$(sed -nr '$s/(^[^ ]*).*/\1/p' "file.txt")`

The `-nr` tells `sed` to not output data by default (`-n`) and use extended regular expressions (`-r` to avoid needing to escape the paranthesis otherwise you have to write `\( \))`). The `$` is an address that specifies the last line. The regular expression anchors the beginning of the line with the first `^`, then matches everything that is *not* a space `[^ ]*` and puts that the result into a capture group `( )` and then gets rid of the rest of the line `.*` by replacing the line with the capture group `\1`, then print `p` to print the line.